# Regex matching anything else but

Tags: regex

So I have these values:
1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123
1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123.123.1234.12
1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.12345555.232

The idea is that all of them have a different length. So I need to match everything is after first 5 elements (by elements I mean values resulted after slitting it by ".")
So I need to keep the bold text
1.232.123.3.123.**214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123**
1.232.123.3.123.**214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123.123.1234.12**
1.232.123.3.123.**214.124.1241245124.12345555.232**

Based on this I tried the following:
`([0-9]*[.]){8}` which is returning the root (the value that I need to remove)
I tried somehow to match the rest of it, but nothing seems to work
This one matches the n elements from the end, but this number is variable and it doesn't help too much: `(([.][0-9]*){3})$`

I'd need something like this:
[image]
For this I used `(([.][0-9]*){7})$` but as the length of the end can be variable, I can't use it

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this pattern `([0-9]*[.]){8}` can give you partial matches as it is unanchored and it also could match 8 dots like `........` as the digits are optional.

This pattern `(([.][0-9]*){3})$` matches 3 dots followed by optional digits till the end of the string.

---

You can use a capture group, and repeat the dot before or after matching a digit to not match consecutive dots `..`

```
^(?:\d+\.){5}(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\d+\.){5}` Repeat 5 times matching 1+ digits followed by a dot
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat matching `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZrMunX/1)

Example using Javascript

```js
const regex = /^(?:\d+\.){5}(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)$/;
[
  "1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123",
  "1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123.123.1234.12",
  "1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.12345555.232",
  "1.232.123.3.123",
  "1.232.123.3.123.",
  "1.232.123.3.123.1",
  "........"
].forEach(s => {
  const match = s.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
  }
});
```

---

Using a finite length in Java you might also use a match only, asserting 5 repetitions to the left from the start of the string.

```
(?<=^\d{1,10}\.\d{1,10}\.\d{1,10}\.\d{1,10}\.\d{1,10}\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dmAJJ1/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/8hUjg2)

Comment: "@The fourth bird" any idea how could I match only the values of the group1, because the line you posted it matches the entire row?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu What is the tool or language?

Comment: It is used in java. Bassically I send the value and the regex. The regex should match only the elements starting from the fifth one, because in java, there is a function used to remove what regex matches. So I need to match all values, except for frst 5 elements, so I can remove the rest of them

Comment: It's nothing that I can do to change the functionallity, unfortunatlly

Comment: "@The fourth bird" I've updated the question with an example of what I have to match, I didn't expect to be this hard xD

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu I have added an example using Javascript getting the group 1 value

Comment: "@The fourth bird" this is strange. I've just run it on an online regex processor for this value: 1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123, and I get exactlly 1 match for the entire value. I also put it in my tool ,and it returns nothing, so it matches the entire value (as I said, the tool removes what regex matches).<br>
If you go to this: https://regexr.com/ and try the code you posted on this value: 1.232.123.3.123.214.124.1241245124.123124124.124124.124124.123123123, will it match for you all the values starting form the fifth one?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu Ah, you are using it in Java. For some reason I thought Javascript. Can you control the Java code? See this Java example to get the group 1 value https://ideone.com/Xk6Wwq

Comment: "@The fourth bird" no, that's why it is so hard, If I could change the code, I wouldn't even bother using regex xD

Comment: "@The fourth bird" but the online regex processor returns the same result as java tool, it seems to work only on javascript xD

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu The code also works on regex, but you have to enable the multiline flag for the example data. See https://regexr.com/60gcq

Comment: "@The fourth bird" ooo, I see, that makes sense. Thank you a lot for the time and all explanations.

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu I have added an example for Java with a finite lookbehind to get the match only at the end of the answer.

Comment: "@The fourth bird" THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED. thank you so much